# Encode portion of path using PHP

Tags: php, url, curl

I need to encode only part of the $delete path. Only the @ in the email address and # in the property. I know how to use urlencode for the whole thing but not on just that. The way it works, is it loops through to get the properties and most of them include # in the name. Anyone who can help modify so that this works would be greatly appreciated!

The delete:

```
 $delete = "http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
```

1. Here you can see **$user_id** this will be an email address BUT the @ symbol needs to be encoded.
2. The properties which follow at the very end, has a # within the name, this needs to also be encoded. For example, one property name *userprofile#external.created_date*

Here is the code so far:

```
 <?php

    $user_id="john_smith@ourwiki.com";

    $url=('http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/users/=john_smith@ourwiki.com/properties');
    $xmlString=file_get_contents($url);

    $delete = "http://admin:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/deki/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

     function curl_fetch($url,$username,$password,$method='DELETE')
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // returns output as a string instead of echoing it
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); // if your server requires basic auth do this
        return  curl_exec($ch);
    }

    foreach($xml->property as $property) {
      $name = $property['name']; // the name is stored in the attribute
      curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name),'admin','12345');
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Please trim down your sample code to target only what you are having issues with. I cannot really identify what data you want to escape or where it is being used.

Comment: @erisco Thanks for replying to this. My apologies for not making it so clear. I edited the post and tried to better document what needs to be fixed. It all has to do with an existing api. I have a for loop that is running through to capture all of the given properties for a specific user_id. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? str_replace($string, array('@', '#'), array('%40', '%23'));

The urlencode function does not allow you to limit it to a subset of characters.

Comment: No I haven't tried that. Where in the code exactly would I do this? And would it replace it in each of the properties as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well anywhere you need to escape those characters. so $user_id and where every the hash tag would be.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So I would just replace $string with the $user_id. For the property, would str_replace just go inside the for loop? I'm assuming I would just do the replace on the $name variable after it has been assigned. Let me know if that sounds right.

Comment: Also, I tried using the str_replace right after the initial $user_id is defined. Then I simply printed the variable afterwards to see if it had done the replace but it had not. Is there something that I might be missing?